# Understanding SOAPAction in http header (Java somewhat involved)

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I noticed my home router has some configuration field "TR-069 CLIENT CONFIGURATION" and some obscure address that I noticed gets resolved quite often each day. (Yes obviously to config the router remotely.. or something) But I want to see what is being sent. So wrote a very simple "web server" in Java to read in HTTP requests (the field in the router was with a normal `http://` address) and print them out. (i set that field to point to my computer where the little server is running)

And im getting these:

```
Host: 192.168.1.2
User-Agent: Allegro-Software-WebClient/4.07
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2767
SOAPAction:
```

Was kind of hoping SOAPAction: wouldnt be empty but what does this mean, is it some deprecated feature of the router that just happens to keep going? (its a d-link ADSL Router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There would be multiple soap envelopes in HTTP Request.**

[TR-069 spec](http://perl-cwmp.googlecode.com/files/TR-069.pdf) says

> When there is more than one envelope
>   in a single HTTP Request, the
>   SOAPAction header in the HTTP Request
>   MUST have no value (with no quotes),
>   indicating that this header provides
>   no information as to the intent of the
>   message. That is, it should appear as
>   follows:
>
> SOAPAction: